# media query for bootstrap / ci application failing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, media-queries

I am trying to change some images in my code to uses classes... so that I can create media queries.  The first step for me was to "move" the image from my view into the css file.

I'm trying to replace this code in my view: (this code works)

```
 94         <div class="item">
 95           <img src="assets/images/outside/front2.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">
 96           <div class="container">
 97             <div class="carousel-caption">
 98               <h1>Welcome to the test site</h1>
 99               <p></p>
100               <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">push me</a></p>-->
101             </div>
102           </div>
103         </div>
```

with this:

```
 94         <div class="item"><div class="testclass"></div>
 95          <!-- <img src="assets/images/outside/front2.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt=""> -->
 96           <div class="container">
 97             <div class="carousel-caption">
 98               <h1>Welcome to the test site</h1>
 99               <p></p>
100               <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">push me</a></p>-->
101             </div>
102           </div>
103         </div>
```

You'll notice that the only different is that I've commented out the image, and I've added a  instead. 
I have included the file that contains the testclass definition in the view, like so:

```
 29     <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
 30     <link href="assets/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
 31     <link href="assets/css/ttest.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And ttest.css looks like this:

```
  1 /* ### Media queries #### */
  2 .testclass {
  3   height: 100%;
  4   background-image: url(../images/outside/front2.jpg);
  5   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  6   background-size: contain;
  7   background-position-x: center;
  8 }
```

But the image will not appear.  I don't see anything jumping out at me in the F12 developer window to say there's an error.

The file structure is like this:

```
dl@testbox [~/public_html/testapp.com/assets]$ ls -lah
total 24K
drwxrwxrwx 6 dl dl 4.0K Mar 24 16:52 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 dl dl 4.0K Mar 25 03:43 ../
drwxrwxrwx 2 dl dl 4.0K Mar 26 18:01 css/
drwxrwxrwx 2 dl dl 4.0K Mar 24 16:48 fonts/
drwxrwxrwx 4 dl dl 4.0K Mar 24 16:52 images/
drwxrwxrwx 2 dl dl 4.0K Mar 24 16:52 js/
```

The ttest.css file lives in the assets/css folder...
Any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting your image url in inverted commas `background-image: url(` **'** `../images/outside/front2.jpg` **'** `);`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't seeing the image because `.testclass`'s rendered height is 0px.

You need to either set a fixed height to `.testclass` or to `.item`.
However, setting a fixed height to `.item` and leaving `.testclass` at 100% will cause `.testclass` to take up the entire height of `.item`, pushing the rest of `.item`'s content down.

Judging by your previous img element, I would guess this should work:

```
.testclass {
    height: 300px;
    ...
}
```

Some examples (pretend the green is your background image):
How it behaves currently: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2p2gnd3/7/)
With fixed height on `.item`: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2p2gnd3/6/)
With fixed height on `.testclass`: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2p2gnd3/5/)